# Invalid Argument in jQuery.js at line 116 !

Tags: jquery

This is my script to get color tag ! Which works in Firefox but in IE shows error.

```
<code>

document.documentElement.className += 'js_active';
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery(".color_tag_cloud a").each(function(){
  var links = jQuery(this).attr("href");
   jQuery(this).removeAttr("title");
   jQuery(this).attr("title",jQuery(this).text());

    if(links.indexOf("?")!=-1){
    var query =links.split("=")[1];
    var str = "#".concat(query);
     jQuery(this).css("background",str);
    }else{
    var color = links.split("colors/")[1];
    var query = color.split("/")[0];
    var str = "#".concat(query);
    jQuery(this).css("background",str);
    }
  });

 jQuery(".color_tag_cloud a").hover( function() {
   jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
    },function() {
   jQuery(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
 });
});
```

and my html is look like this.

```
<code><div class="color_tag_cloud">
<a href="http://www.freecssshowcase.com/colors/e30074/">PINK</a>
.......
</div>

</code>
```

Comment: Debugging in IE and it seems to occur on the 3rd iteration of the `jQuery(".color_tag_cloud a").each` loop. I can't see anything wrong with the 3rd link though...

Answer (score 2):

Your script is setting some invalid hex color codes with the jQuery's `css` method, and IE is complaining about this.

Log the values of your `str` variable, and you will see:

[image: invalid-colors-codes.png]